# What is wrong with the package that successfully downloaded but still not exist yet in R?

Tags: r, installation, r-package

[image]

please help me, what is wrong with the steps or the package?

I am trying to install it again and again but still not working (the package still not exist yet)

Comment: your R version is a few years old. It is probably worth upgrading : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/

Comment: @user20650 That needs to be worded more strongly. They can't use these packages if they don't upgrade R.